# Returning A String From .loc Query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
```

If I select the Name from row index 1, I get a simple string object:

```
df.loc[1].Name
Out[9]: 'nick'
```

But if I select the row containing Age == 15, I get an object I can't seem to coerce into a string object

```
df.loc[df.Age==15].Name
Out[11]:1    nick
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

```
type(df.loc[df.Age==15].Name)
Out[38]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

Ok, its a series, that's cool, get the first element:

```
df.loc[df.Age==15].Name[0]
KeyError: 0
```

Well, that didn't work, lets ask for the actual key:

```
df.loc[df.Age==15].Name[1]
Out[40]: 'nick'
```

Yeah! That works! ... but if I knew the actual key I wouldn't have done the query in the first place!

How do I get the string value from this Name field if I know the Age? In my real use-case I know Age is unique.

Comment: `df.loc[df.Age==15].Name.item()`

Comment: can't you use `iloc[]` ? `df.loc[df.Age==15].Name.iloc[0]` ? or `df.loc[df.Age==15].Name.iat[0]`

Comment: Thanks @anky_91, I'm used to R or C. I was blown away when the behavior totally changed from what I was expecting.

Comment: @RonJensen-WeareallMonica `loc` is primarily a key based indexer , for position based, we always use `iloc` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @ayhan said in comment above, you can use [`pandas.Series.item()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.item.html) like this:

```
>>> df.loc[df.Age==15, 'Name'].values.item()
'nick'
```

You can also use [`pandas.Series.array`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.array.html#pandas.Series.array):

```
>>> df.loc[df.Age==15, 'Name'].array[0]
'nick'
```

or [`pandas.Series.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html#pandas.Series.to_numpy):

```
>>> df.loc[df.Age==15, 'Name'].to_numpy()[0]
'nick'
```

Comment: FutureWarning: `item` has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version

Comment: Sorry, I have just edited the answer. The current solution should not throw FutureWarning.

Comment: @RonJensen-WeareallMonica I think they decided not to follow through that deprecation. What is the version you are using?

Comment: I am using pandas version 0.25.3.

Comment: @JaroslavBezděk It is available in 1.0.1 Here's the issue for "undeprecating" https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29250

Comment: Python 3.7.6 and Pandas 0.25.3

Comment: I editted my answer with another solutions, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

@anky_91 is right. You should use .iloc, for this case.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
print(df.loc[df.Age==14].iloc[0].Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
df.loc[df[df['Age'] == 15].index[0], 'Name']
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to consider the use of query. If you only want to get the str, you can use:

```
df.query('Age==15').Name.values[0]
```

This might be more intuitive given the first try of Ron.